# How to make a flip effect to switch panels on QT Quick 2

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I'm using QT Quick 2 to construct a UI. It is made up of 5 panels which should be displayed one at a time. So I want to write a flip effect to switch among these panels. I find the Flipable element effect is what I want, but it can do only two panels flip. How can I get this done for 5 panels?

The 5 panels will be triggered to appear randomly (by 5 buttons) not sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

In front and back of flipable, put more than one Panels, but only one visible at a time. Have two global variables, which decide what is the current active panel on a side. Then on each flip, write logic to make one of these panels visible and others invisible, one by one.

```
front : Item {

Panel1 {opacity: 1}
Panel2 {opacity: 0}
Panel3 {opacity: 0}
Panel4 {opacity: 0}
Panel5 {opacity: 0} 
}

back : Item {

Panel1 {opacity: 0}
Panel2 {opacity: 1}
Panel3 {opacity: 0}
Panel4 {opacity: 0}
Panel5 {opacity: 0} 
}
```

---

**Edit:**

If you want persistence in the screens ( as you have mentioned in the comment), you can proceed like this :

> front : Item 
>   {
>
> ```
> Panel1 {id : front_1 ;opacity: 1}
> Panel3 {id : front_3 ;opacity: 0}
> Panel5 {id : front_5 ;opacity: 0}
> ```
>
> }
>
> back : Item 
>   {
>
> ```
> Panel2 { id : back_2 ; opacity: 1}
> Panel4 { id : back_4 ; opacity: 0}
> Panel6 { id : back_6 ; opacity: 0}
> ```
>
> }
>
> property int front_Panel : 1
>
> property int back_Panel  : 2
>
> ```
>  MouseArea  
>  {
>      anchors.fill: parent
>      onClicked: 
>      {
>          if( side === Flipable.Front )
>          {
>               back_Panel = front_Panel+1
>
>               if( back_Panel === 2 )
>               {
>                  back_2.opacity = 1
>                  back_4.opacity = 0
>                  back_6.opacity = 0
>               } 
>
>               else if( back_Panel === 4 )
>               {
>                  back_2.opacity = 0
>                  back_4.opacity = 1
>                  back_6.opacity = 0
>               }  
>
>               else 
>               {
>                  back_2.opacity = 0
>                  back_4.opacity = 0
>                  back_6.opacity = 1
>               }  
>          }
>
>          else
>          {
>               front_Panel =  back_Panel + 1
>
>               if( front_Panel === 7 )
>                   front_Panel = 1
>
>               if( front_Panel === 1 )
>               {
>                  front_1.opacity = 1
>                  front_3.opacity = 0
>                  front_5.opacity = 0
>               } 
>
>               else if( front_Panel === 3 )
>               {
>                  front_1.opacity = 0
>                  front_3.opacity = 1
>                  front_5.opacity = 0
>               }  
>
>               else 
>               {
>                  front_1.opacity = 0
>                  front_3.opacity = 0
>                  front_5.opacity = 1
>               }  
>          }
>
>          flipable.flipped = !flipable.flipped 
>      } 
>  }
> ```

There is a catch though, you should have **even** number of panels :-)

Comment: But the Panel1 in front Item won't share states with Panel1 in back Item. They are not the same Panel1 instance, right?

Comment: @user1777342 Yes, you are right. I have done an edit for  this requirement. Just check. But it will work only for even number of panels.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't quite understand your code. How does it flip when I switch within the same side panels? For example, between Panel2 and Panel4?

Comment: @user1777342 The example I have written is assuming you want to have a h=behavior like this : Panel 1 is shown by default. User clicks on the panel, it flick, and shows panel 2. On again clicking, it flicks back and shows another panel and so on. So you can go from panel 1 to 2 to 3 to 4 to 5 to 1 on every subsequent click. If you have a different requirement, try to improve the question and adding more details about the requirements.

Comment: Sorry for unclear question. I have 5 buttons to trigger which panel to be shown. So the switch is random not sequential.